# System.Data.DataRowView instead of real values

Tags: c#

I have below code. When I run the progam and run once stored procedure with parameter e.g. 223 and then I run it with parameter e.g 315 ant after that run once again with parameter I got System.Data.DataRowView” instead of real values. Could You please help me with below?

```
private void GetServers()
    {
        IDBManager dbManager = new DBManager (DataProvider.SqlServer);
        dbManager.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=base;  Integrated Security = SSPI;";

        try
        {
            dbManager.Open();
            dbManager.CreateParameters(1);
            dbManager.AddParameters(0,"@report_id", (txtReportID.Text));
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Servers");
            ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_get_servers_from_report_test");              
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                chkdListBoxServers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                chkdListBoxServers.DisplayMember = "Servers";
                chkdListBoxServers.ValueMember = "server_name";                 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No servers or incorrect report id");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            dbManager.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess `chkdListBoxServers.DisplayMember = "server_name";` would be fine.

Comment: Will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `chkdListBoxServers.DisplayMember = "server_name";` would be fine.

Comment: Wiktor's solution works for me. I am wondering why DisplayMember property has to be set the same as ValueMember property? It is strange to me that I able to run the stored prodecure only twice and after that it stops working correctly. Appreciate if someone can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code

```
//DataSet ds = new DataSet("Servers"); //delete this

            var ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_get_servers_from_report_test");
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( I also noticed that when I try to execute the procedure with 3rd parameter it also returns System.Data.DataRowView” instead of real values